# How to solve equation when variable is inside min function?

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

I have the following equation:
$$x \cdot 14 - \min(x \cdot 14 \cdot 0.0025 + 2, 133) = 280$$

I need to find the value of $x$. What is the preferred approach?
I am coming back to math after a long time, am thinking of using piecewise function.
In my use case I need to find the $x$ value in an excel sheet also  but I am out of ideas so far.

Thanks in advance

Comment: It would probably be best to consider two cases - when the first argument of the minimum function is less than $133$, and the case when it is greater than it.

Comment: Thanks for the insight, I was thinking of using if else statement in  excel. Something like calculating first without the min function the value  of x, then calculating the value of x⋅14⋅0.0025+2 with the calculated  value of x. If this would be higher then 133, then I would recalculate x using as min value 133 in the function. It does not seem like an  elegant solution but will give it a try

Comment: maybe to write it more compactly: the equation is equivalent to $14x(1- 0.0025\epsilon) - 2 \epsilon - 133(1-\epsilon) = 280$, where $\epsilon = 1$ when $14x0.0025+2<133$, $\epsilon = 0$ otherwise; the idea is to write $\min(a,b) = \epsilon a + (1-\epsilon) b$

Answer (score 1):

You can write $\min(a,b) = \epsilon a + (1-\epsilon)b$, where $\epsilon = 1$ if $a < b$, $\epsilon = 0$ otherwise.

Then the equation is equivalent to

$$14x - \epsilon (14x0.0025+2) - (1-\epsilon)133 = 280$$
$$14x(1-0.0025\epsilon) = 280 + 2\epsilon + 133(1-\epsilon)$$
$$x = \frac{280 + 2\epsilon + 133(1-\epsilon)}{14(1-0.0025\epsilon)}$$

So you can evaluate the expression for $\epsilon = 0,1$ and check if the solution is valid: in this example, $x_0 = \frac{280+133}{14}$ and have to check if it's true that $14x_00.0025+2\geq 133$... false! Then check if for $x_1 = \frac{280+2}{14(1-0.0025)}$ is it true that $14x_10.0025+2 \leq 133$...